# Error on sqoop2 job submission

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm getting an error on sqoop2 job submission.

```
sqoop:000> start job --jid 1
Submission details
Job id: 1
Status: FAILURE_ON_SUBMIT 
Creation date: 2013-11-06 11:21:30 IST
Last update date: 2013-11-06 11:21:30 IST

Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/usr/local/sqoop/server/webapps/sqoop/WEB-INF/lib/sqoop-common-1.99.3.jar
```

Do we need to put all sqoop jar files on HDFS?

I’m running sqoop jobs on the same master node of hadoop 2.2.0

Comment: Please enable the verbose mode and rerun the submission start command. http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/CommandLineClient.html#set-option-function

Comment: `Stack trace: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://master:9000/opt/hcluster/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-hadoop200/server/webapps/sqoop/WEB-INF/lib/sqoop-common-1.99.3.jar
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1110)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
         `

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:264)

Comment: The three comments above were the error stacks in sqoop.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied all required jar libs into the hdfs finally and it worked.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /usr/local/sqoop/server/webapps/sqoop/WEB-INF/lib/
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /usr/local/sqoop/server/webapps/sqoop/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar /usr/local/sqoop/server/webapps/sqoop/WEB-INF/lib/
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify `mapred-site.xml` file.

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

I succeeded